# sql server management studio showing null for duplicated values

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server Management Studio and I am having some issues joining tables and achieving a specific query. I have looked around on the forum of questions and can't seem to find a solution that works. I have attached an image that has the two tables and the query that I am trying to get.

[image: tables].

Basically, if the pallet number duplicates the tag names will be `NULL`. In order for me to use any of the joins (right or left) I know that I need an `ON` clause, but in my second table I have no `Id` column to use for it.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

I only did this because I found it to be an odd question. Please be sure to read [Sean's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange) comment carefully.

```
declare @table1 table (id int, palletNumber int)
insert into @table1 values
(1000,1),
(2000,1),
(3000,2),
(4000,1)

declare @table2 table (tagName varchar(16), tagType varchar(8))
insert into @table2 values
('name 1','int'),
('name 2','real'),
('name 3','int'),
('name 4','int')

select
    id,
    palletNumber,
    case when id = min(id) over (partition by palletNumber order by palletNumber) then tagName else null end as tagName
from
    @table1
    cross join @table2 
order by 
    id, tagName
```